# failed to deploy WAR artifact on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, artifact

Everything was working fine few minutes earlier.

I just deleted my changes and downloaded it again, so the only thing I had to do was configure **tomcat** again, but I am pretty sure I did it the same way.

Now, when I try to deploy my application, I got this error:

```
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.254 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.257 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Feb 6 2018 23:10:25 UTC
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.257 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.28.0
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.257 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8.1
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.257 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.259 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.259 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.259 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.260 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.260 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\matt\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_cost-control_4
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.260 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\matt\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.261 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\matt\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_cost-control_4\conf\logging.properties
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.261 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.261 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.264 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.265 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.265 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\matt\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_cost-control_4
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.269 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\matt\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.269 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\matt\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\temp
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.269 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.269 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
03-Mar-2018 23:35:59.269 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
03-Mar-2018 23:36:00.313 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017]
03-Mar-2018 23:36:00.894 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
03-Mar-2018 23:36:00.936 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
03-Mar-2018 23:36:00.956 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
03-Mar-2018 23:36:00.959 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
03-Mar-2018 23:36:00.977 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2592 ms
03-Mar-2018 23:36:01.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
03-Mar-2018 23:36:01.082 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
03-Mar-2018 23:36:01.100 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
03-Mar-2018 23:36:01.121 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
03-Mar-2018 23:36:01.126 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 148 ms
Connected to server
[2018-03-03 11:36:01,356] Artifact cost-control:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
03-Mar-2018 23:36:02.153 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
03-Mar-2018 23:36:02.157 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2018-03-03 11:36:02,183] Artifact cost-control:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
03-Mar-2018 23:36:11.101 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\matt\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\manager]
03-Mar-2018 23:36:11.192 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\matt\Desktop\JAVA\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\webapps\manager] has finished in [90] ms
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a server log file?

Comment: And on from @MateuszKleinert's request -- `Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file`

Comment: Sure, but where do I find it? 

I was searching in C:\Users\...\apache-tomcat-8.5.28-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.28\logs 

but there is no such log file

Comment: Just a guess, but check if this can help, seems to be similar issue: [Tomcat 9.0.0.M19: failed to deploy simple WAR artifact](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171174)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help